# php multidimensional array to string or table

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

how can I output this array into html table? 
for each row I would like to output it like this, within the foreach;

```
echo "<td>".$lat."</td><td>".$long."</td>";
```

as per example on https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html

I have tried the code

```
$api_url = "https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?start=Berlin-Main-Station;52.52282,13.37011&destination1=East-Side-Gallery;52.50341,13.44429&destination2=Olympiastadion;52.51293,13.24021&end=HERE-Berlin-Campus;52.53066,13.38511&mode=fastest;car&app_id=ID&app_code=CODE"; 
$api_response = file_get_contents($api_url);
$api_response_decoded = json_decode($api_response, true); 
foreach($api_response_decoded as $api_response_decoded_row){ 
    print_r($api_response_decoded_row[0][waypoints]); 
}
```

and also tried

```
print_r($api_response_decoded_row[0][waypoints][id]);
```

and also tried

```
echo($api_response_decoded_row[0][waypoints][id]);
```

and also tried

```
implode($api_response_decoded_row[0][waypoints][id]);
```

Comment: please help me improve the question - why the downvote? I did google it and have spent about 2 hours trying various things from stackoverflow and other sites - I certainly tried to solve it myself first!

Comment: Where do you try to output the array in an html table? You have a json but you just use `print_r`, `echo` and `implode`, where is the html structure? Can you show us what you get from those 3 way and what you want?

Comment: for each row `echo "<td>".$lat."</td><td>".$long."</td>";` see edit, does that clarify?

Comment: Where do you use the `echo "<td>".$lat."</td><td>".$long."</td>";` with your data?  It should be in your foreach no?

Comment: @MickaelLeger exactly right thank you

Comment: did you try `$api_response_decoded_row['results']['waypoints']` ?

Comment: Also, thanks to whoever had downvoted, for removing :-).

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara thanks very much

Comment: @MickaelLeger thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it if the comments didn't already help you enough.

```
foreach($api_response_decoded as $api_response_decoded_rows){ 

  foreach ($api_response_decoded_rows[0]['waypoints'] as $waypoint) {

    $html = '
            <td>'.$waypoint['lat'].'</td>
            <td>'.$waypoint['lng'].'</td>
            ';

    echo $html;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to commenters and answerers. In case it helps someone else, full working code is therefore;

```
$api_url = "https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json?start=Berlin-Main-Station;52.52282,13.37011&destination1=East-Side-Gallery;52.50341,13.44429&destination2=Olympiastadion;52.51293,13.24021&end=HERE-Berlin-Campus;52.53066,13.38511&mode=fastest;car&app_id=ID&app_code=CODE"; 
$api_response = file_get_contents($api_url);
$api_response_decoded = json_decode($api_response, true); 
echo "<table>";
foreach($api_response_decoded as $api_response_decoded_rows){ 
  foreach ($api_response_decoded_rows[0]['waypoints'] as $waypoint) {
    $html = '<tr><td>'.$waypoint['sequence'].'</td><td>'.$waypoint['id'].'</td><td>'.$waypoint['lat'].'</td><td>'.$waypoint['lng'].'</td></tr>';
    echo $html;
  }
} 
echo "</table>";
```